# What type of rigid body rotation can best be learned by neural networks?

Tags: robotic-arm, rotation, orientation, reinforcement-learning, neural-networks

I am training a reinforcement learning network in simulation for a robot which at the current stage learns Euler Angles to rotate the end-effector based on the actual state. The performance is overall not that satisfying. My network architecture is rather small and contains only two hidden layers. So, I would like to know what type of rotations can best be learned by neural networks? Euler Angles, Rotation matrices or Quaternions?

If someone could recommend a publication or paper for this topic, I would be very interested. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ardi, this is certainly an interesting topic, but I'm afraid that questions which ask for research papers are effectively opinion polls, which are [discouraged on stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

Every three-dimensional parameterization of rotations has [singularity](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1006093?casa_token=VoOK1j7KTacAAAAA:hbJNYwrLG9gc68KnJ1sWJFRAr9QOTBvjyshM3HbdBoll1UwlJaD66Ie-rY0wqesMU_yyHzCugA). So even if you would implement the kinematics directly you would still run into trouble for some rotations when using Euler angles (or any other three-dimensional parameterization).

Quaternions, or more accurately unit quaternions, do not have such singularities. Though, do not have a unique parameterization (negating the quaternion would represent the same rotation). However, if you only consider the kinematics then unit quaternions already don't pose any issue in my opinion. So using a three by three rotation matrix would not really simplify the kinematics at the cost of higher over-parameterization. Additionally, unit quaternions are also easier than rotation matrices to "normalize", so ensuring that a four dimensional vector represents a unit quaternion vs that a three by three matrix represents a rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is the continuity of the representation. [This paper](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/html/Zhou_On_the_Continuity_of_Rotation_Representations_in_Neural_Networks_CVPR_2019_paper.html) explains it.